How do I add a colored line to the active tab of my custom Chrome theme?
I've seen themes in which they do it, like this one but not a guide that shows how to do that. Also, all themes I've seen that have such line also have another line that goes through the entire browser toolbar; is there a way to not have that?

Solution: see this post
